# Container size depending on his content (text)

Tags: flutter, flutter-container, flutter-card

I want my container to have different size depending on their content (in this case a text), if one user write a longer text the container will be biger and if another user write a shorter text the container will be smaller.

Is it possible? And if not is there another way to do it?

Thanks

[This is what I want to achieve (it's a screenshot of Samsung note app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shksX.jpg)

Comment: Did you try yourself can you show your code?

Comment: Yes I tried to do it multiple time but it's always end up in a failure, but it's finally working thanks to the answer down below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to not assign `width` or `height` to the `Container` so it will resize depending on the `child`:

```dart
Container(
     color: Colors.red,
     child: const Text("Hi there111"),
)
```

If you want to control max width and max height you will use `Container`'s `constraints` field

```dart
Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: 200,
      ),
      child: const Text("Hi there11122222222"),
)
```

And of course you can give it `minWidth` and `minHeight` in `BoxConstraints`.

Result when you are under `maxWidth`

[image]

Result when you have text so long that it goes over the bounds of `maxWidth`, in this case height resizes automatically:

[image]

You can also add padding for better look:

```dart
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    color: Colors.red,
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
      maxWidth: 200,
    ),
    child: const Text("Hi there11122222222222222222"),
)
```

[image]

But for other types of widgets, other than `Text` it will be much safer if you wrap them with `FittedBox` like this,  *notice the `Text` widget* :

```dart
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    color: Colors.red,
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
      maxWidth: 200,
    ),
    child: FittedBox(
       fit: BoxFit.fill,
       child: const Text("asfasfasfasfasf")
    ),

)
```

Comment: Thank you mate for taking the time to explain it clearly

Comment: Glad to help <3